# Is it impossible to overload a generic method in VB.NET by changing only the type constraint and the return type?

Tags: vb.net, generics

I have these two nearly identical methods:

```
''' <summary>
''' Converts a <see cref="DBNull"/> to an actual Nothing value.
''' </summary>
''' <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
''' <param name="val"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
Public Shared Function DBNullToNull(Of T As Structure)(ByVal val As Object) As T?
    If TypeOf val Is DBNull Then Return Nothing Else Return Val
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Converts a <see cref="DBNull"/> to an actual Nothing value.
''' </summary>
''' <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
''' <param name="val"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
Public Shared Function DBNullToNull(Of T As Class)(ByVal val As Object) As T
    If TypeOf val Is DBNull Then Return Nothing Else Return Val
End Function
```

But I get this compile error:

> Public Shared Function DBNullToNull(Of T As Structure)(val As Object) As T?' and 'Public Shared Function DBNullToNull(Of T As Class)(val As Object) As T' cannot overload each other because they differ only by return types.

But they differ not only by return types, but also by generic type constraints (one works on structures, the other on classes) which are mutually exclusive. Is this still not allowed?

Of course I can rename them so they don't conflict, but that would be a bit annoying! Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I would presume that generic constraints aren't part of the function signature.  Jon Skeet discusses this in the context of C# (where this is definitively the case) here: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/10/28/overloading-and-generic-constraints/ .  I presume that either this is imposed by .NET or VB has made the same design choice as C# here.

Comment: Check the rules at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/overloads When you think about, the compiler needs to know which method to call. How would it know if the only difference was the return type?

Comment: It seems like differentiating on the generic type constraint could work in this particular case but, in other cases, it might be possible that one object could satisfy multiple sets of constraints.

Comment: To expand a little on @jmcilhinney 's comment, this would be a strong reason not to allow it; as far as I know, in the existing design, any instances of an ambiguous overloaded function call can be resolved by a type cast on one of the parameters to force it into one of the candidates.  Overloading by generic constraint, however, would be impossible to resolve if there were constraint ambiguity, because there would be no way to force it to one of the candidates.